# Confused about the relationship between 「丸」 as in 「日本丸」 and 「麻呂」 as in 「君麻呂」

Tags: etymology

Firstly I found that 「丸{まる}」 originated from 「麻呂{まろ}」:

[日本水路協会：船の名前にはなぜ「丸」が付くのか](http://www.jha.or.jp/jp/jha/charts/story/2004/08_2.html)

Then this answer said that 「麻呂{まろ}」 originated from 「おまる」:

[古代日本人の名前についている 「～麻呂」 には何か意味があるのですか？](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1111442251)

It started to make me feel kind of circular: from おまる to まろ to まる(again).

Then I came across this answer saying 「丸｛まる｝」 directly originated from 「おまる」:

[人名に付ける「丸」の語原について (おまる？それとも麻呂？)](http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1262937857)

Confused <@_@>

Answer (score 4):

My understanding:

[image]

Giving children degrading names was widespread, and is still practiced in some part of world, in order to deceive wicked spirits.