What does 丸 mean here: 「若者をのせた太平丸は歌島港にかえった」
What does the 丸 in 太平丸 mean here:

先刻、まだ残照のあるうちに、若者をのせた太平丸は歌島港にかえった。若者は船主ともう一人の朋輩と一緒に、毎日このエンジンのついた小舟に乗って漁に行くのである。


Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21567/9831

Im japanese.
丸というのは日本の船⛴の名前によくつけられるものです。
人の名前にもつけられることがあります。
ラグビー選手にも五郎丸という人がいます。

人の名前にもつけられることがあります -- [牛若丸]{うしわかまる}みたいな男の子の名前（昔の男子の幼名）の話かと思ったのですが　（五郎丸さんは五郎丸歩さんだから苗字のような気が）

ごめんなさい。日本人は苗字も名前も名前と一括りにする傾向があります。

例えば、「ここに名前を書いてください。」と言われると、苗字と名前のことを言っている場合が多いです。

はい、では回答の「人の名前にもつけられることがあります。 ラグビー選手にも五郎丸という人がいます。」の部分は、「～丸」が苗字にも下の名前にも同じくよく付けられるという意味だと解釈して良いですか

下の名前につける人は少ないです。

調べてみると、日本人の総人口を１億人としたとき、苗字の中に丸〜or〜丸があるのは0.4%くらいでした。ごめんなさい。「よく」という言葉は船だけでした。

もっと詳しく言うならアニメanimeや漫画comicなら下の名前に丸がついていても普通に感じますが、実際の人物の下の名前に丸がついていることは珍しく感じます。
